# SonarLint Change Allowed Cognitive Complexity

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I would like to change the allowed cognitive complexity of a method in SonarLint from the default of 15 to a lower values such as 10. I am using the SonarLint plugin for eclipse.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In connected mode the threshold for cognitive complexity can be defined in solarlint (csharpsquid:S3776). Please reference [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/issues/1007)

Comment: I'm not in a position to verify this anymore. I'm sorry.